# OpenACC: How to apply the reduction clause to a struct variable

Tags: openacc

I simply need to apply the `reduction(max: )` clause to `Dts->t` but nothing seems to work, I tried `reduction(max:Dts.t), reduction(max:Dts->t), reduction(max:Dts)` and `reduction(max:t)`.

```
  #pragma acc parallel loop collapse(3) reduction(max:t) present(Dts) 
        for (k = KBEG; k <= KEND; k++){
        for (j = JBEG; j <= JEND; j++){
        for (i = IBEG; i <= IEND; i++){
          Dts->t = MAX(Dts->t, C_dt[k][j][i]);
         
        }}}
```

I get these types of errors:

```
PGC-S-0035-Syntax error: Recovery attempted by replacing '.' by ',' (update_stage.c: 450)
PGC-S-0035-Syntax error: Recovery attempted by replacing identifier present by accparallel (update_stage.c: 450)
PGC-S-0040-Illegal use of symbol, invDt_hyp (update_stage.c: 450)
PGC-S-0036-Syntax error: Recovery attempted by inserting <nl> before keyword for (update_stage.c: 451)
PGC-S-0978-The clause parallel is deprecated; use clause gang instead (update_stage.c: 451)
PGC-S-0374-Clause gang(value) not allowed in #pragma acc parallel loop (update_stage.c: 451)
```

Dts is a variable of type Step.

```
typedef struct Step_{
  double *cmax; 
  double t;  
  .
  .
  .
} Step;
```

The loop I'm trying to accelerate is in a routine called in the main function. In the main function, Dts is defined and there I write

```
#pragma acc enter data create(Dts)

#pragma acc enter data copyin(Dts.t[:1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the OpenACC standard, reduction variables cannot be a member of a composite variable.  The easiest work around to this limitation is to use a local scalar variable and then assign the result back to the struct member.

Something like:

```
  double tmax;
  ...
  tmax = Dts->t;
  #pragma acc parallel loop collapse(3) reduction(max:tmax) present(Dts) 
        for (k = KBEG; k <= KEND; k++){
        for (j = JBEG; j <= JEND; j++){
        for (i = IBEG; i <= IEND; i++){
          tmax = MAX(tmax, C_dt[k][j][i]);
         
        }}}
  Dts->t = tmax;
```

If you need the value of Dts->t on the device, either add it to an update device directive after the assignment or put "tmax" in a data region and the assignment into serial regions.

```
 // best if you need the value of Dts->t on both the host and device
  double tmax;
  ...
  tmax = Dts->t;
  #pragma acc parallel loop collapse(3) reduction(max:tmax) present(Dts) 
        for (k = KBEG; k <= KEND; k++){
        for (j = JBEG; j <= JEND; j++){
        for (i = IBEG; i <= IEND; i++){
          tmax = MAX(tmax, C_dt[k][j][i]);
         
        }}}
  Dts->t = tmax;
  #pragma acc update device(Dts->t)
```

or

```
  // best if you only need the value of Dts->t on the device
  double tmax;
  ...
  #pragma acc data create(tmax) 
  {
  #pragma acc serial present(Dts)
  {
  tmax = Dts->t;
  }
  #pragma acc parallel loop collapse(3) reduction(max:tmax) present(Dts) 
        for (k = KBEG; k <= KEND; k++){
        for (j = JBEG; j <= JEND; j++){
        for (i = IBEG; i <= IEND; i++){
          tmax = MAX(tmax, C_dt[k][j][i]);
         
        }}}
  #pragma acc serial present(Dts)
  {
  Dts->t = tmax;
  }
  }
```